# jquery validation plugin - file upload

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using jquery validation plugin for validating my form. I have one file field in form for uploading documents.

`<input type="file" name="policyBriefFiles" id="policyBriefFiles" multiple="multiple">`

Here is my validation code for this field.

```
policyBriefFiles: {
         extension:'xlsx,pdf',
         filesize: 2097152,  
     },
```

Now I want users to select maximum two files, but with multiple attribute specified with file user can select any number of files.

How do I restrict users to select maximum two files and no more? Is there any rule available in jquery validation plugin for this? (like maxFile: 2)

I don't mind any other workaround also.

Comment: I think this link can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8212041/it-is-possible-to-validate-the-size-and-type-of-input-file-in-html5

Comment: @DoanMinhTien Thanks for your answer. In the link they are validating file size. I want to validate number of files selected.

Comment: you can do something like it: document.getElementById('policyBriefFiles').files.length to get number of files after user selected

Comment: Yup. That worked. Thanks.

Comment: *"Is there any rule available in jquery validation plugin"* ~ why not first check the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/methods/) or look at the source code of [the plugin](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js) and the [additional-methods](http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/additional-methods.js) file?

Comment: I had. I was just looking for a quick and easy solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made custom validation method for this. Here it is

```
$.validator.addMethod("maxFilesToSelect", function(value, element, params) {
    var fileCount = element.files.length;
    if(fileCount > params){
        return false;
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
},  'Select no more than 2 files');
```

And specify rule as

```
policyBriefFiles: {
         extension:'xlsx,pdf',
         filesize: 2097152,  
         maxFilesToSelect : 2,
     },
```

Working as charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

We can simple add `maxfiles: 3` method which is available in the additional-method.js file of the plugin.
`maxfiles: 3` // no of max files you want.